# Erro com setOnTouchListener

Tags: java, android

Eae, venho recebendo o segundo erro ao rodar um app no AndroidStudio

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.vinicius.login, PID: 3519
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vinicius.login/com.example.vinicius.login.inicio}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnTouchListener(android.view.View$OnTouchListener)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnTouchListener(android.view.View$OnTouchListener)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.vinicius.login.inicio.onCreate(inicio.java:40)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Pelo que pude ver ele aponta o erro como a linha 40 onde existe um botão, não sei se o erro é só esse mas aguardo respostas e ajudas, segue o código abaixo

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class inicio extends Activity{



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        /********************************/
         /*    Define os botões  */
        /********************************/
        Button led1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LED1);
        Button led2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LED2);
        Button led3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LED3);
        Button led4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LED4);
        Button led5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LED5);
        Button led6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LED6);

        /*******************************************************/
         /*  Seta um Onclick e Onchange  */
        /*******************************************************/

        led6.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    /* button is led 3 */
                    new Background_get().execute("led6=1");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    new Background_get().execute("led6=0");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        led5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    /* button UP */
                    new Background_get().execute("led5=1");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    new Background_get().execute("led5=0");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        led4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    /* button BACK */
                    new Background_get().execute("led4=1");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    new Background_get().execute("led4=0");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        led3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    /* button RIGHT */
                    new Background_get().execute("led3=1");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    new Background_get().execute("led3=0");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        led2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    /* button LEFT */
                    new Background_get().execute("led2=1");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    new Background_get().execute("led2=0");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        led1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    /* button FRONT */
                    new Background_get().execute("led1=1");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    new Background_get().execute("led1=0");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}


class Background_get extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
                /* Conexão com o Raspberry PI 3, solicitação HTML de comando PHP servidor APACHE  */
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.101/?" + params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                result.append(inputLine).append("\n");

            in.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            return result.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

meu XML é o seguinte

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4F4F4F"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.vinicius.login.inicio">

    <TextView
        android:text="LOGIN™"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#B5B5B5"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="FRONT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LED1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="BACK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LED4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LED2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LED2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/LED2" />

    <Button
        android:text="RIGHT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LED3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/LED4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LED1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/LED1" />

    <Button
        android:text="LEFT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LED2"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/LED1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/LED1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/LED1" />

    <Button
        android:text="DOWN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LED6"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LED5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/LED5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="XY"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#B5B5B5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/LED2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:text="UP"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LED5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/LED6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LED4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/LED4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Z"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#B5B5B5"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/LED6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/LED5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="34dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_partial_secure"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LED3" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Falta `setContentView(R.layout.layoutDaActivity)`

Comment: Sou iniciante com o android ainda, pode ser mais especifico com relação ao local que falta isso? Onde está faltando  "setContentView(R.id.activity_login) " ?

Comment: Após `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: Thanks amigo! O problema foi solucionado! Agora me resta estudar mais para aprender a função  de setContentView, abraço! (y)

Comment: Se de facto quer aprender esse é o caminho. Não basta ter o problema solucionado, só deve ficar satisfeito quando perceber a solução.

Comment: Sem dúvidas (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o amigo acima citou, falou o setContentView, que "infla" o arquivo XML de layout no JAVA para que os objetos da UI possam ser instanciados. Por isso você tomou o erro de "null object", visto que o JAVA não encontrou nenhuma referência ao botão que você tentou usar.